# Windows Service Bus on Amazon Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, azureservicebus

A simple question:

Is it possible to use Windows Service Bus on Amazon cloud to build SOA based solution?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj193022%28v=azure.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Barisa, this is possible to do. Service Bus 1.0 for Windows Server can be run on any VM/Box running Windows Server so you can host it anywhere.

Comment: Documentation for this is at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj193022(Azure.10).aspx